# How does our rails application find routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know the exact code has written to call routes.rb file in our rails application. thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I need to create a new file for routes (for eg `routes1.rb`), where should I change so that applications points to `routes1.rb`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the exact line you're looking for  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb#L40

If you want your app to be aware of other routes files, in your `config/application.rb` add the following line

```
config.paths['config/routes'] << 'config/routes1.rb'
```

Explanation: You see, Rails application is basically an Engine. More on that [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). Each engine can have customized paths for where to search for things like models, helpers, routes, etc. This customized value can be a directory or a specific file. So simply we're telling our main Rails engine to include an extra routes file (`config/routes1.rb`) in addition to the default value of `config/routes.rb`. I hope this makes sense :).

Answer (score 0):

There you go: inspect each class and you have the code on github linked there

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html

```
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/inspector.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb
actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb
railties/lib/rails/engine.rb
railties/lib/rails/info_controller.rb
```